# How To Get Started With React Admin On Windows

Tags: react-admin

It is difficult to get started or setup this entire repo in Windows?

Can you please give step by step approach to set this up in Windows or a short video tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue. My fix was to:

1. Delete the react-admin directory if you already have a clone from the repo
2. Update Node and Yarn
   -- After update I am currently running Node v10.13.0 && Yarn v1.12.3
3. Grab a fresh clone of the repo
4. Then from the react-admin directory run:

   ```
   yarn
   ```

Once that completes:

```
yarn build
```

And finally once that completes:

```
yarn run-demo
```

lmk if this works for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much. Until we add a `Windows` section in the README, here's how you can get started:

- run `yarn` to install all dependencies
- run `yarn run-simple` to start the playground app and test your changes

There are more scripts in the root `package.json` file to run tests, demos, etc.

If you need help with something more specific, please precise it in your question

Comment: Thanks Gildas for d steps i am almost done.Initially i was using npm install in Windows and not working.Now with yarn and yarn run-demo i m almost there. But getting this error:                                                                         
Starting the development server...
Failed to compile.
./src/fakeServer/rest.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../node_modules/data-generator which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/

Comment: Run `./node_modules/.bin/lerna build` at the root directory before. This will build all the react-admin packages

Comment: mayank@P4ALAPPP MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Apps/newAppsHere/react-admin-master
$ npm install --global lerna
added 606 packages in 168.338s
mayank@P4ALAPPP MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Apps/newAppsHere/react-admin-master
$ ./node_modules/.bin/lerna build
ERR! lerna Invalid command!
ERR! lerna Pass --help to see all available commands and options.
mayank@P4ALAPPP MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Apps/newAppsHere/react-admin-master
$ yarn ./node_modules/.bin/lerna build
yarn run v1.9.4
error Command "./node_modules/.bin/lerna" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command

Comment: Sorry getting the above error while running those packages

Comment: Did you run `yarn` at the root directory first ?

Comment: Yes i did run yarn at the root first and then yarn run-demo where i was facing those issues. Hence i followed your next steps you gave but got below error.                    
mayank@P4ALAPPP MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Apps/newAppsHere/react-admin-master $ yarn ./node_modules/.bin/lerna build yarn run v1.9.4 error Command "./node_modules/.bin/lerna" not found. info Visit yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command

Comment: Can you check your `node_modules/.bin` folder at the project root?